# what's the meaning of ::system in Linux Embedded Arm?

Tags: c++, qt, arm, embedded-linux

I'm checking a snippet made in Qt fo embedded, that allow to set the serial port parameter.
Its not clear the meaning of the following instruction: I understand it sets communication parameter, but I don't understand "::system" (probably the launch of an external command?) and the possible values variable "ret" could assume:

```
    int ret=::system( RS232_1_SET="stty -F /dev/ttymxc1 230400 parodd -cstopb cs8 -echo");
```

Does anyone could explain it in a detailed way OR give me some link to the related sintax?

Thanks

Paolo

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: In C++ a symbol like `::symbol` means it is in the [global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+global+namespace).